# deselect all switches in a tableview

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3, switch-statement

have a table view which consists of various different xib files for different question types. One such question is a multi option answer. For this row type, the row itself consists of another tableview each row has a label and switch for the number of options for that question and an overall switch above this inner table to mark this question as na. so When this na switch is tapped, I neeed to deselect all switches existing in the inner row. I have tried the following, but i have an issue if there are so many options that not all cells in the inner table are visible on screen:

```
@IBAction func switchChange(_ sender: UISwitch) {

        let mcAnswerTable = sender.superview?.superview?.superview?.superview as! UITableView

            for rows in mcAnswerTable.visibleCells {

                if condition {
                    if let row = rows as? MCAnswerCell {
                        row.enabled.setOn(false, animated: true)
                    }
                }

            }
       }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically avoid to manipulate the *view* (cell) directly unless you have no choice.

Here you have one. Create an appropriate *model* and use the *controller* to make the changes.

---

- For the table view containing the switches use a custom class (let's call it `Foo`) with an `isSelected` property as data source model.
- In `cellForRow` set the `isOn` property of the switch to the state of `isSelected`.
- Subclass the table view cell and add a property of `Foo` and an `IBAction` for the switch.
- In `cellForRow` pass the `Foo` instance to the custom cell to be able to update the `isSelected` property in the `IBAction`. Due to reference semantics the changes persist in the data source.
- To deselect the switches call `dataSourceArray.forEach {$0.isSelected = false}` und `tableView.reloadData()`

Another huge benefit is that you have access to the state of all switches even of the cells which are not visible currently.

Comment: I have added a new question for my handling the switches in cellforrow as you answered the q asked here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43876065/setting-switches-on-off-for-rows-in-an-inner-table-within-a-row-in-an-outer-t